Validate uniqeness with data from multiple tables in livewire
I'm trying to run a validation rule in the context of livewire 3.0 (laravel 10) with data from multiple tables. So far, my code looks like so:
$validated = $this->validate([ 
  'nombre' => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('resultados_aprendizaje','nombre')->where(function (Builder $query) use ($grupoId) {
  return $query->join('criterios_evaluacion', 'resultados_aprendizaje.id', '=', 'criterios_evaluacion.ra_id')->where('criterios_evaluacion.grupo_id', $grupoId);
    })
  ],
]); 

Tables structure is simple:
resultados_aprendizaje('id','nombre')
criterios_evaluacion('id','nombre','ra_id','grupo_id')

As you can guess, criterios_evaluacion.ra_id is a foreign key to the corresponding record in resultados_aprendizaje. My goal is to make sure a user doesn't create two records in resultados_aprendizaje in the same group with same name.
Error:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'criterios_evaluacion.grupo_id' in 'where clause' 

Sql generated:
select
  count(*) as aggregate
from
  `resultados_aprendizaje`
where
  `nombre` = RA
  and (`criterios_evaluacion`.`grupo_id` = 5)

I have been trying different approaches but none of them work, so any help is appreciated. I'm not even sure what I'm trying to do is possible in this way...

Using Rule::unique with a join query in Laravel can be a bit tricky because Rule::unique is generally used for simple unique constraints on a single table. However, you can achieve similar functionality by combining a custom validation rule with a join query to check for uniqueness across related tables.
Here's an example of how you can implement this in Laravel:
Step-by-Step Implementation
Create a Custom Validation Rule:
First, create a custom validation rule. You can use the Artisan command to generate this rule:
php artisan make:rule UniqueWithJoin

Implement the Custom Validation Rule:
Open the generated file app/Rules/UniqueWithJoin.php and implement the validation logic. Here's an example:
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class UniqueWithJoin implements Rule
{
    protected $table;
    protected $column;
    protected $relatedTable;
    protected $relatedColumn;
    protected $value;

    public function __construct($table, $column, $relatedTable, $relatedColumn)
    {
        $this->table = $table;
        $this->column = $column;
        $this->relatedTable = $relatedTable;
        $this->relatedColumn = $relatedColumn;
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;

        $count = DB::table($this->table)
            ->join($this->relatedTable, "{$this->relatedTable}.{$this->relatedColumn}", '=', "{$this->table}.{$this->column}")
            ->where("{$this->table}.{$this->column}", $this->value)
            ->count();

        return $count === 0;
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return "The :attribute has already been taken.";
    }
}

Use the Custom Rule in Your Request Validation:
You can now use this custom validation rule in your request validation. Here's an example of how to use it in a controller or a form request:
use App\Rules\UniqueWithJoin;

$request->validate([
    'your_field' => [
        'required',
        new UniqueWithJoin('your_table', 'your_column', 'related_table', 'related_column')
    ],
]);

